# Programming the night vision sensor

Tags: video

I have set this up with the PIR sensor and a night camera.

I have been able to write a simple(ish) program (P1) so it so that when motion is detected, it saves an image – the filename of the image is the date and time when it is recorded.  The program keeps running until i is interrupted with CTRL C.

I have modified this program (P2) so that when it detects motion, it start a video recording, also onto a file whose name is the date and time. Using time.sleep(10), I can get it to stop recording after 10 seconds.

I would like to be able to change the program so that it keeps recording until the motion stops but I don’t understand the detall of the camera control to do this, and would appreciate some help with this.

The relevant part of P2 is

## When motion is detected, an image is saved

## The filename is the current date and time

## A beep is played when motion is detected

```
 while True:


      while GPIO.input(motionsensorpin):
```

## Update filename to current date and time

```
           filename = '{:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}'.format(datetime.datetime.now())+'.h264'
```

## Play a beep sound

```
           pygame.mixer.music.play()
           print(filename)
```

## Save an image to the current filename

```
           camera.start_recording(filename)
           time.sleep(10)
           camera.stop_recording()
```

Any help gratefully received.

Answer (score -1):

Why reinvent the wheel check motionEye it does all that and more

Comment: where is the fun in that? :)

Comment: Simple answer is that I didn't know about MotionEye.  I'll look for it and have a go.  There is so much information out there about Raspberry PI that it is not easy to find the right bit.  That's the great thing about these forums.  But I also think Rob has a point - it's more fun to do it yourself.  So I would still appreciated help to modfy my code to solve the problem.  Thanks all.

Comment: I've now had a look at MotionEye, and discovered that it is a complete package.  I doing this project mainly for fun, and to improve my programming.  So I would still be grateful for any help in where I go next with my code.

Comment: Fair enough, I'd assumed the objective was a security camera. I'm not familiar with the programming language you're using, is it python ?

Comment: Yes, Python.  I think I need to understand more about how the camera software works.  BTW - not convinced I could use it as a real security camera - would need a weatherproof box!

Comment: I've done just that housing it all in a dummy camera purchased from ebay

Comment: Can you give me details of the dummy camera?  Did you program it in Python?  If so, could you let me see the code?  Thanks

Comment: the dummy camera was a tight fit I had to mount the Pi diagonally to squeeze it in so would recommend something a little larger, just search for 'dummy CCTV' on ebay or amazon. As previously mentioned I used motionEye OS

Comment: Thanks Bra1n.  Didn't clock that you were the person who directed me to Motion Eye.  Will check out dummy CCTV box if/when I get it going with Python.